# Content slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

Hey I’m building this Content Slideshow

I have two problems:
1:  I had it working, but now it’s broken…I’m spending the entire morning trying to figure out what I broke.
2 : When it was working, the slide will start at Content DIV three then jump to 1. And I wanted it to start at 1, then 2, then 3, and keeps respeating about every 10 seconds.

Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/myislandshop/2AW8a/4/

Any help will be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: What about using the [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)? Easier to maintain and already implemented perfectly. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you remove the redundant `window.load` http://jsfiddle.net/2AW8a/5/

Answer (score 1):

*Full Disclosure: This is plugin that I have developed myself*

Check out [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) - either to use, or get some ideas on how to implement your  own content slider.

Comment: You have linked this page on a fair number of pages, if this is something you developed, you should place a disclaimer in your answer, as the community tends to frown on self promotion, which this looks like.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I was wondering if I was breaking any kind of unwritten rule by promoting my own work - I've only suggested it in questions that are relevant. I'll modify my answers with a disclaimer.

Comment: No worries, there is a bit in the faq about promotion -> http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion but with added disclaimer and the fact as you say it's relevant in the q's you've answered you should be fine :)